# Flask + Tornado application - how to communicate with server (Connection refused)

Tags: python, flask, tornado

I have followed the online documentation for installing a [GNU health FHIR REST server](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_Health/FHIR_REST_server).

I have managed to get the REST server application running on my server machine. [According to the documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_Health/Using_the_FHIR_REST_server), the following endpoints should be available from my server:

```
List all patients (http://localhost:5000/Patient)
Show info for patient id #1 (http://localhost:5000/Patient/1)
List all patients with ana in name (http://localhost:5000/Patient?name=ana)

# etc ...
```

This is the Python code that is used to start the Tornado server:

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.options import define, options
from app import create_app
from config import ProductionConfig

define("port", default=5000, help="Port to listen on", type=int)
#app = create_app(config=ProductionConfig)
app = create_app() #DebugConfig
http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(options.port)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I used `curl` to try to interrogate the server:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/Patient
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
```

**Note:** I'm guessing (from the code pasted above), that the Tornado server is listening on port 5000. I modified the code to print out the value of `options.port, but for some reason, it doesn't get printed to the console; also failed to log the value to a file (file not written, and no error message given)- so not sure whats going on.

I double checked with `lsof` to see which ports are open:

```
$ lsof -i
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python2 23147 morpheous    4u  IPv6 592698      0t0  TCP localhost:51950->localhost:8000 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I need help in establishing which port Tornado is running, so I can use curl to query the REST API.

Comment: This code looks correct, and it works if I substitute my own `create_app` function. The problem must be something in the `app` or `config` modules.

Comment: @BenDarnell which port was your Tornado instance running on? Also, in my question, I wanted to know how to talk to the server using `curl` - how would I do that?

Comment: Also, do you know how I can debug the tornado application code (code provided in my question). The inability to print to console or log variables to file is making it more difficult to debug and resolve the issue.

Comment: I was using 5000, and the same curl command. Printing to the console works normally in a Tornado application, so start by figuring out what's going on with your print problem before going into the network issues. Try adding a print at every line to see where it stops.

Comment: Create server and only listen, `listen` isn't `alive`, any socket can run without a `OK` signal ?

Comment: @dsgdfg Sorry, I didn't understand what you wrote. Could you please clarify? Cheers

Comment: Established to `8000` not `5000` ! Every server need a response data otherwise you can't get any answer. Your query is `curl http://localhost:5000/Patient` but which instance/function handle `path query` ? Your server is `Listen` but don't returned any data !   Another point (my opinion) learning tree is `Socket >> WSGI >> [DJANGO,FLASK,TORNADO, ETC]`, if your think is `basic` why using `complex` modules ? **Prepare all answer before making a query, can't build a answer on a request !**

Comment: `app = create_app()` include some configuration but active, mean your server not binding to `5000` port, you changed everything(`define("port", default=5000, help="Port to listen on", type=int)`)  with next line.

Comment: What do you have going in `ProductionConfig` and `create_app`?

Comment: do a `lsof -P |grep "^Python .*(LISTEN)$"`.  I think your port may be overridden in `ProductionConfig` or `create_app`

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused will come if either permission problem or nothing running on that port. In your case i guess there is nothing running on 5000.

please check with this command

> ss -ltp

You may have to use **sudo** to list all tcp connections with port and user

> (e.x) sudo ss -ltp

My output:

LISTEN     0      128    *:6379  *:*  users:(("redis-server",pid=12325,fd=5))

Note: I just listed my one output of my list here.

This just tells me redis is running on 6379 port.

If in case tornado is running it will list that for you while firing this command.

Let me know if any problem you are facing in this.